# Preventing db.get() from returning outdated records

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on an app that has users taking turns put()-ing data into the datastore, which then has the id broadcast to the user via channel. Sometimes, when the users get(), it'll show the previous user's changes. How can I prevent this? Is there a way to have the put() block until it's written?

Comment: Post some code.  Are you using transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ancestor queries in the docs.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

You are now seeing eventually consistent results, although in this case you need strongly consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Operations on the datastore take place in two parts: the commit phase, and the apply phase.

You can read more about it at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Datastore_Writes_and_Data_Visibility

But the short version is that datastore operations return after the commit phase, not after the apply phase. You may have told the datastore to add/update/delete an object, but it'll take some milliseconds for that operation to execute even after the specific op has returned.

You might need to add an artificial delay to your code.

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I don't think that adding an artifical delay is the right solution. What do you do if the apply phase took more than 1 second in this case ?